# Upgrading CentOS 4.8 to 5.5 (x86_64)

Tags: centos, httpd, upgrade

I have CentOS 4.8 with httpd installed, Since httpd 2.2.23 version not supported on CentOS 4.8 Now I want to upgrade same to 5.5 without disturbing existing state of Application Stack

I tried with yum but stuck with the dependencies errors, Is there any solution that will help me to get out of this mesh

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really advise you to consider wiping the box and reinstalling it fresh with CentOS 5.  Major version CentOS installs are very difficult.

Plus if this machine has been running a few years, it's accumulated a lot of cruft that you can get rid of.  Make a good backup and reinstall.  If this is a production server, try building a duplicate machine, validating it, and then switching over.

This is a great time to look at setting up a configuration management system like [cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org) or [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com) to move the system state off the machine and make this sort of upgrade easier in the future.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is not made to upgraded between major versions via yum (or much at all, really). You will need to work through the problems one at a time as you encounter them.